# REG GENERIC METHOD

Tags: c#, generics

I had a thought on using the generic method in c# as like we do in c++.

Normally a method looks like this:

```
public static (void/int/string) methodname((datatype) partameter)
{
              return ...;
}
```

I had a thought whether can we implement the generics to this method like this:

```
public static <T> methodname(<T> partameter)
{
              return ...;
}
```

Using  as a generic to define the datatype.

Can anyone pls suggest whether the above declaration is correct and can be used in c#?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite like that, no. It would be:

```
public static T MethodName<T>(T parameter)
{
    ...
}
```

The `<T>` after `MethodName` shows that it's introducing a type parameter.

EDIT: As per the comment, you can't use this for a void method - you can't use `void` as a type argument, basically.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that this does not work for 'void' (first type in googler1's example).